# Create multiples *.bat file

Tags: batch-file, text, split

I have one bat file in which I run a program, *(`PROGRAM_NAME`)*, with multiples set of parameters, *(`input1.txt`, `input2.txt`, `...`, `inputn.txt`)* like this:

run.bat

```
pushd path
PROGRAM_NAME input1.txt
move RESULT another_path
...
pushd path
PROGRAM_NAME inputn.txt
move RESULT another_path
```

Now I want to run this `*.bat` file in parallel like this:

run_1.bat

```
pushd path
PROGRAM_NAME input1.txt
move RESULT another_path
```

run_n.bat

```
pushd path
PROGRAM_NAME inputn.txt
move RESULT another_path
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it literally the string `input` plus a number?

Comment: @Stephan yes, ..............................

Answer (score 1):

To start another process (needed to run something in parallel), use the [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command. The `/d` switch sets the working folder for the new process (instead of your `pushd`). Use `&` to execute a second command as soon as the first one is finished. You need to escape it with a caret `^`, else it would be interpreted as `(start program) & move` instead of `start (program & move)`:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  start "%%i" /d "path" PROGRAM_NAME Input%%i.txt ^& move result another_path\
)
```

(Note: depending on `PROGRAM_NAME` this may not work without some adaption)